# cfc that bring in additional functions via include

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, application.cfc, fw1

My application.cfc starts with:

`<cfcomponent extends="org.corfield.framework">`

later on `void function setupApplication() output="false"   {`

I have

```
// tools
include "initapp.cfm";
```

initapp.cfm has nothing but functions in it. Things like:

```
<!--- Helper functions --->
<cfscript>
string function stripHTML(str) output="false" {
return REReplaceNoCase(arguments.str,"<[^>]*>","","ALL");
}

application.stripHTML = stripHTML;

</cfscript>
```

The nature of the functions is NOT associated with a session. Is there a better way to make functions available globally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to put helper functions together for use in CFCs, one option may be to use the component.cfc file.

> **Using the component.cfc file**
>
> All CFCs automatically extend the ColdFusion
>   WEB-INF/cftags/component.cfc component. (The WEB-INF directory is in
>   the cf_root/wwwroot directory on ColdFusion configured with an
>   embedded J2EE server. It is in the cf_root directory when you deploy
>   ColdFusion on a J2EE server.) This CFC is distributed as a zero-length
>   file. **You can use it for any core methods or properties that you want
>   all CFCs in your ColdFusion application server instance to inherit.**
>
> *Note: When you install a newer version of ColdFusion, the installation
>   procedure replaces the existing component.cfc file with a new version.
>   Therefore, before upgrading, you should save any code that you have
>   added to the component.cfc file, and then copy the code into the new
>   component.cfc file.*

If that solution is TOO global you can extend your helper cfc, but it has to be done in every cfc and doesn't answer your one-time-set-it-and-forget-it idea. See [Using CFCs effectively](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=buildingComponents_30.html)

If your helper functions are for use in .cfm files, I'd do like Adam suggested. I usually put my helper functions in a "tools" cfc located in a CFC folder and make it an application scoped cfc.

```
function onApplicationStart(){
    application.tools = createObject("component", "cfc.tools");
}
```

One of my helper functions logs the time it takes to index a solr collection. Using it looks like

```
<cfset application.tools.logSolrIndex('collectionName',getTickCount()-start,qFileList.recordCount)>
```

**Last resort:**
If you had to stick with an include for use outside of the application.cfc, I might simply include initapp.cfm onRequest() before you include your page.

Comment: bad link there is

Answer (score 3):

Put the functions in a library CFC, and then put an instance of that CFC in the application scope in `onApplicationStart()`.

That said, you'd be kinda breaking encapsulation if you then referenced this application-scoped CFC within other CFCs, which is a consideration (not necessarily a deal breaker, but a consideration).

You could look at some sort of dependency injection approach to mitigate this (eg: [ColdSpring](http://www.coldspringframework.org/))

Whichever way I ended up doing it, I would *not* be doing it the way you're doing it, I'm afraid.

Comment: Couldn't you just use extends="myGeneralFunctions" to 'import' these methods?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it was not possible to have multiple 'extends'.